# virtual keyboard in kubuntu, Plasma 5.10

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, sddm

I read [several announcements](https://www.kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.10.0.php) that Plasma 5.10 will feature the qtvirtualkeyboard, an on-screen keyboard for devices that do not always have a physical keyboard at hand. I added the kubuntu backports ppa and checked in Discover that I get pre-release updates.
Apparently, the following packages are already installed:

```
qml-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard
qtvirtualkeyboard-plugin
qtvirtualkeyboard5-examples
```

Nevertheless, I can't find a way to actually use the virtual keyboard nor helpful instructions on the internet so far..

I would mostly need the keyboard for login. The keyboard symbol in the lower left corner seen in many screenshots of Plasma 5.10 does not show on my device. Any ideas?

Thank you for your thoughts and for help!

My System:

- Kubuntu 17.04 64-bit
- KDE Plasma: 5.10.4
- KDE Frameworks: 5.36.0
- Qt: 5.7.1
- Kernel: 4.10.0-29-generic

Comment: The SDDM needs fix: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/pull/803 . More: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=309&t=140504#p376771 . You could file a bug report against the sddm package.

Comment: @user26687 thank you very much for that quick reply. I haven't noticed that post before, I'll take a more thorough look at this tonight :)